# WEIRD Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ` 'if' (T_IF) ERROR`

Tags: php, parsing, if-statement

I'm having trouble with this error message:

`WEIRD Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) ERROR LINE 11`

And the code is this:

```
foreach($admins as $admin){ 
echo "
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>".++$menuCounter."</td>
            <td><a href='adminprofile.php?user_name=".$admin['user_name']."'>".$admin['user_name']."</a>
            </td>
            <td><a id='myModal1' href='mailto:".$admin['email_address']."' target='_top'>".$admin['email_address']."</td>
            <td>".$admin['date_joined']."</td>
            <td>".$admin['group_admin']."</td>
            <td>";if($admin['admin_level'] == 0 || if($admin['admin_level'] == 1 || $admin['admin_level'] == 9)
            { 
                echo "<a href='admindelete.php?table_id=".$admin['table_id']."'><span class='label label-danger'>REMOVE</span></a></td>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "";
            } 
            echo "
        </tr>
    </tbody>
";  
}
```

**And Line 11 is this:**

```
<td>";if($admin['admin_level'] == 0 || if($admin['admin_level'] == 1 || $admin['admin_level'] == 9)
```

So what is the problem with that?

Comment: replace `;` with `.` on line no 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple condition in same `if` statement
Change

```
 if($admin['admin_level'] == 0 || if($admin['admin_level'] == 1 || $admin['admin_level'] == 9)
```

To

```
if($admin['admin_level'] == 0 || $admin['admin_level'] == 1 || $admin['admin_level'] == 9)
```